# When writing JSX code, one of my wrapper divs isn't showing on the page, or in the code of the inspect tool

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

Okay so first of all here is my code

```
<div
        className={"item-wrapper"}
        >
          <div className="item-wrapper-content">
            <div className="words-wrapper">
                <div className="item-name">
                    {name}
                </div>
                <div className="price">
                    <h1>${price}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="calories">
                    <h1>Calories: {calories}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="description">
                    {description}
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div className="image">
              <div className="item-name">
                {name}
              </div>
              <img 
                src={image}
                alt="thing"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

For some reason the "item-wrapper-content" div is not shown on the page, instead it goes from item-wrapper > words-wrapper. I have built a card feature, where the "image" div shows on the front, and the "words-wrapper" is supposed to show on the back when the cards are moused over, but this bug is preventing scss styles from applying to the words-wrapper and image divs.
These styles are being applied to item-wrapper-content:

```
position: relative;
text-align: center;
transition: transform 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Here is where I am hosting the WIP portfolio app on heroku:
https://rtg-capstone.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how, but when I pushed to heroku it updated my .scss but not my .js files. I did the git push process again and that fixed it